# Getting a ListView in Report mode to work on a dialog with WS_EX_COMPOSITED?

Tags: winapi, gdi, comctl32

There is a bug / limitation using `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` on a dialog where a `ListView` control in report mode won't show up.  Apparently this is known, but I can't find the official information on it.  From the looks, it has been broke since at least XP, if it had been fixed years ago it wouldn't still be an issue.

So my question is, is there a known way to get the `ListView` to work in Report Mode when the dialog has `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` extended style?

If not, is there a ready to use double-buffer implementation that can be used?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample in order to send feedback about this?